# Translating Camera Matrix in OpenGL

Tags: c++, math, opengl, matrix, 3d

So until recently I have been transforming my OpenGL objects like this (Rotation_Matrix is GLfloat[16], I get it from a quaternion that stores the object's orientation, works well):

```
glTranslatef(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z);
glMultMatrixf(Rotation_Matrix);
```

BUT I recently discovered that I can just do glMultMatrixf() if I do this first:

```
Rotation_Matrix[12] = Position.x;
Rotation_Matrix[13] = Position.y;
Rotation_Matrix[14] = Position.z;
```

This translates everything well, and I believe this is important for transitioning to OpenGL 3.0+ later?  Because we have to have our own matrices, I think.

So I switched over to new system without glTranslatef(), and all works well except my camera.  For camera I get Camera_Matrix from *inverse* of orientation quaternion, it used to work fine like this:

```
glMultMatrixf(Camera_Matrix);
glTranslatef(-CameraPos.x, -CameraPos.y, -CameraPos.z);
```

But if I set values 12, 13 and 14 to -CameraPos, the camera doesn't move right, sometimes going forward makes it go sideways and vice versa, and the more I move the more the movement is wrong.

How can I add translation to the camera's transformation matrix properly?

**SOLUTION:**

Instead of using normal position, you must calculate dot products as such (remember these are OpenGL matrices!):

```
GLfloat xDot = Position.x * m_RotationMatrix[0] +
               Position.y * m_RotationMatrix[4] +
               Position.z * m_RotationMatrix[8];

GLfloat yDot = Position.x * m_RotationMatrix[1] +
               Position.y * m_RotationMatrix[5] +
               Position.z * m_RotationMatrix[9];

GLfloat zDot = Position.x * m_RotationMatrix[2] +
               Position.y * m_RotationMatrix[6] +
               Position.z * m_RotationMatrix[10];

m_RotationMatrix[12] = -xDot;
m_RotationMatrix[13] = -yDot;
m_RotationMatrix[14] = -zDot;
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `glm`? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model transformation for the camera would be

```
M = T * R
```

Since the View transformation is the inverse, this is

```
V = R^-1 * T^-1
```

This implies that the overall rotation contains a rotated translation vector. You have to calculate it from the dot products:

```
translation.x = -dot(position, right vector)
translation.y = -dot(position, up vector)
translation.z = -dot(position, direction vector)
```

You can retrieve those vectors from the matrix. They are in the first three columns / rows.

Comment: Thank you brother! This works indeed, I will update main post to display solution for others.

Answer (score 0):

You're translating in world space, probably. You want to be translating in view/camera space. Make sure to read up in your favorite reference, or http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter04.html. Looking forward, it could be a good idea to not rely on opengl for matrix math (deprecated). Consider using glm.

Comment: Sorry but how exactly can OpenGL's matrix math library become deprecated? Matrix algebra hasn't changed in hundreds of years.

Comment: that's because the matrix algebra isn't. You still use that, but calls like glTranslatef are deprecated. They're not part of the core spec, and might not be supported in the future.